# Mongoose subdoc.pull() only removing last objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of subdocuments in my model, and I am using the Mongoose pull() method to remove them. I am looping through `items.num.length`, and if `items.num[i]` is 'on', then I want to remove the subdocument with `id` at `items.id[i]`. This is working if the `num[items.num.length]` is 'on' (last item), or if the last item and sequentially previous items are selected. But not if anything else if selected.

```
if(items.num[i] === 'on') {
   user.groceryList.pull(items.id[i]);
   user.save();
   if(!Array.isArray(items.id)) {
      user.groceryList.pull(items.id);
      user.save();
   }
}
```